# To load controller using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below codeigniter code i placed the controller.But it is not loading the controller.But it shows The page you requested was not found.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this -> load -> model('country_model');

        }


        function Register() {
                $data['countries'] = $this -> country_model -> get_countries();
                $this -> load -> view('test/post_view', $data);
        }
       }
```

Comment: how u wer tried to access the controller????????

Comment: i tried like this localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/user

Comment: try `localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/user/register` or add an index function inside the controller like `function index(){......}`

Comment: add .php at the end of your file name post_view

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('country_model');

        }


        public function Register() {
                $data['countries'] = $this->country_model->get_countries();
                $this->load->view('test/post_view', $data);
        }
       }
```

The parameters that come behind index.php in your url means the following..
index.php/user/register = go to the controllers user and activate the function register.